# Flutter screen becomes horizontal then portraitup when changing pages

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

Flutter screen becomes horizontal then portraitup when changing pages. How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

By adding the following code to your flutter main method you will always have a landscaped screen orientation.

```
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]).then((_){
       runApp(MyApp()); //replace this with your App Widget
      });
```

You can change to portrait or every other orientation by changing the DeviceOrientation's field (e.g. to DeviceOrientation. portraitUp)

Comment: thanks for the help but i have differents pages and some of my pages are vertical some of my pages are horizontal. I am changing the orientation every page but this is happening when changing pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the orientation on initstate and in dispose like this

```
@override
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
  ]);
}
```

The above code with set the screen in landscape
and in dispose will reset to auto rotate

```
@override
dispose(){
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Does it set the the orientation?

Comment: I already set the orientation. The problem is when changing pages the portrait page is landscape and then portrait again.

Comment: Yeah so when navigating to this page set the orientation and then navigate